# Send image to HTML file from python application file

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am attempting to create a traffic light (good / bad) function within my application. I am using Flask and Jinja templating.

I have my function below and I set a previous functions output(result) as `my_var = traffic_light(result)` to use within the below function-

```py
def traffic_light(result):

    if (result > 10000):
        img = {{ url_for('static', filename='img/traffic-light-green.jpg') }}
        return img

    elif (result < 10000):
        img = {{ url_for('static', filename='img/traffic-light-red.jpg') }}
        return img
```

```
{% if calculation_success == True %}
<br/>
<p>We have calculated your disposable income as :€{{result}}</p>
<img src="{{my_var}}" alt="">
{% endif %}
```

I can return text "Good" and "Bad" to `{{my_var}}` however I am having difficulty outputting .jpg or image files for the traffic light system. I have a feeling its related to the Jinja templating as I am not 100% if `url_for` can be used in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{my_var}}` is Jinja syntax.  This should only be used in templates.

Within the python app, just call the `url_for` function itself:

```
def traffic_light(result):

    if (result > 10000):
        img = url_for('static', filename='img/traffic-light-green.jpg')
        return img

    elif (result < 10000):
        img = url_for('static', filename='img/traffic-light-red.jpg')
        return img
```